# badges in a linkified list group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi there I am fairly new to bootstrap and am using the latest release (3.x) and have a list-group which I have rendered as a linkified group e.g

what I want to end up with is a linkified list-group with a badge on the right of each element, this is simple with an un ordered list group but I cannot get it to work with links

by a linkified group i mean

```
<div class="list-group row">
    @foreach (var dept in Model.Units)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(@dept, "TrackingLists", "TrackingLists", new { department = @dept }, new {@class="list-group-item"})
    }
</div>
```

I'm just not sure where to put the badge here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried, e.g.:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">some text<span class="badge">14</span></a>
</div>
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3753/)

**update:**

If you cant add HTML to your link, use the below HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"> 
        <a href="#">some text</a><span class="badge">14</span>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS
     .list-group-item a {
        display:inline-block;
        width:90%;
        height:100%;
        color:black;
    }
    .list-group-item a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3755/)

Comment: this does of course work and I'll be accepting the answer the issue is that I cannot put html in the text for a @Html.ActionLink in mvc for asp.net..

Comment: the li doesn't work for me in this instance as I particularly didn't want that. but it achieves the same aesthetic.